# How to build a pull-out drawer over content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's a fiddle with code to see show what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/gsnfzn35/1/

What I would like to have happen when user clicks "toggle drawer"

1. Original content (heading + etc.) fades to black, and user can no longer scroll this content
2. New content via drawer pulls out from right side
3. This new content has its own scroll, where there's a fixed final row at the bottom

What is currently happening/ wrong with each step:

1. Content fades to black achieved by a table overlaid over content. However, this content is still scrollable (despite that I tried to set css `overflow`, `hidden`); which means that you can scroll away the black overlay
2. Drawer pulls out successfully, but the mechanism is a bit funky... click toggle drawer again and you'll see that the drawer pulls out more and then pulls in. Furthermore, on neither pull out/in is it as smooth as jQuery UI's documentation shows
3. New content does NOT have its own scroll. Fixed final row is obscuring a bit of the contents of the drawer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is here.
@smrubin is right but something is missing. Overlay is still not fixed. So, When we scroll down and click on the toggle button overlay is not visible of large content. The reason is that overlay has **position: absolute**. It should be **position: fixed**

Check the code below:

```js
$("#popout").click(function() {

  if ($('.fixed table').length == 0) {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    $('.fixed').append(
      $('<table style="width:' + width + 'px;height:' + height + 'px;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);z-index:50;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px">' +
        '</table>').hide().fadeIn(100)
    )
    $(".fixed").css("overflow", "hidden");
  } else {
    $('.fixed table').fadeOut(100, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
    $(".fixed").css("overflow", "auto");
  }

  $(".scroll").toggle("slide", {
    direction: 'right'
  });

})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
}
.fixed {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.fixed,
.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}
.scroll {
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0px;
  width: 33.33%;
  background-color: white;
}
.scroll-fixed-row {
  position: fixed;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <button id="popout">
    Toggle drawer
  </button>
</nav>

<div class="container fixed">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>
      Heading
      </h1>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
      <p>
        Lots of content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container scroll">
  <div class="scroll-fluid-content">
    <h1>
          Peek a boo
          </h1>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
    <p>
      Lots of content
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-fixed-row">
    <p>
      FIXED FINAL ROW
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're correct! This also made me realize, and can you please amend your code, that the `scroll` also needs to have `position:fixed` because that way wherever on the `fixed` page that you've scrolled to, the `scroll` will still "pop up appropriately"

Answer (score 4):

I think I've accomplished a majority of what you're trying to achieve, a couple of notes:

1. Use direction on jquery slide to make it pop out from right: `$(".scroll").toggle("slide", {direction:'right'});`
2. For `overflow: hidden;` to work, you need to set a height for the element.

The rest of the changes you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/gsnfzn35/2/

It includes:

- Slide out from right
- Dim layover and no scrolling on background content
- Scrolling with a fixed footer on the slide out content

I think you should be able to make all the necessary small changes from here.

Comment: I really like this solution because it builds on my work. Staging app here: https://hidden-tundra-8656.herokuapp.com/request. I can't have `body {overflow:hidden}` at the outset as in your answer, because I need user to scroll through items once category is clicked. So I amended your code by adding an `{overflow:hidden}` css to body as well on the cart button click. However, if you load the page, and scroll to the bottom (somehow with no content you can scroll), and THEN click the cart, you'll see a funny white row below the gray overlay, which messes up the formatting. Thoughts?

Comment: Also sorry for delay on this, other things at work blew up and I haven't been able to take a look until now. Actually I just did some testing in mobile; what looks like is happening is that content from the `#catalog` that is supposed to be fully overlayed by the gray and non-scroll is peeking out at the bottom of the `#cart` pullout

Comment: The body scroll and white row is being caused by the rule html, body { height: 100%; }. Either remove that rule or reset it to html, body { height: auto; }

Comment: Hmmm.. ok so then this solution only works if the user clicks the cart when they're at the very top of the page, not if they're anywhere on the page (you can check updated staging app)

Comment: Super helpful in figuring out final answer, upvoted, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS transitions and just use jQuery to fire the opening/closing of the menu. Here is a fiddle showing it in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/NewNine/2jpzj9vw/

In this example, any element with the class `.nav-toggle` will toggle the menu open/close, which fires the very smooth CSS transitions to open/close the menu and bring up the overlay.

Using z-index, you can control which elements appear over/under the overlay. Because it all reacts to a class on the body tag, you can also set `overflow: hidden;` on the body tag when the menu is open which prevents the site from scrolling.

The drawer responds to the height of anything you put in it, which means it will scroll if you add content beyond the height of the browser - no additional code or explicit height setting required.

Comment: This may be the best performing solution. The CSS transition performs much smoother than the jQuery alternatives. And it's nice and lightweight!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not married to jQuery, Polymer gives you a really easy element for handling exactly this:

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-drawer-panel

By using this or Angular, you can easily make these kind of elements as native HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution

https://jsfiddle.net/AldoRomo88/eLurjz37/1/

I’m using velicityjs for animations.
Please check these three points

- Showing/hiding a semitransparent div to block main container changing
  its opacity and display properties
- Changing body’s overflow to
  prevent scrolling on main container
- Changing value of right drawer’s
  property to make it appear from right to left.

```js
var isOpen = false;

$("#popout").click(function() {
  if (isOpen) {
    $('.opacityLayer').velocity('stop').velocity({opacity: 0}, {display: 'none'});
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    $('.drawer').velocity('stop').velocity({right: '-61%'});
  } else {
    $('.opacityLayer').velocity('stop').velocity({opacity: 0.4}, {display: 'block'});
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $('.drawer').velocity('stop').velocity({right: 0});
  }

  isOpen = !isOpen;
})
```